# How to create .webarchive on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, webarchive

Do you know any method to create .`webarchive` file in iPhone ?

I am using `ASIWebPageRequest` to download a `web page` and i want save it in .`webarcive` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to check out this great project - https://github.com/takebayashi/STWebArchiver

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: I have do some modification on the STWebArchiver to make extract more urls you can checkout: [this](https://github.com/Fykec/STWebArchiver)